# When Use Isolate Scope In Directive?

Tags: angularjs

Are there any guidelines on when to isolate the scope of a custom angular directive? 
When is it a good idea and when is it not ? 
From my own limited experience this is what I gathered: when the scope isn't isolated in the directive , the directive will need direct access to the controller's scope to access the data and that could potentially lead to problems :

1. The directive is dependent on the controller , so now the directive code is less re-usable , which was a main point for writing your own directive.
2. The directive can accidentally change values on the controller's scope and this can lead to bugs. Isolating it's scope makes the controller's scope a "private" API for the directive , which is a good thing.

Am I on the right track here ? Are these reasons valid ?

Comment: not deep enough into directive creation myself to give a clear answer but it sounds like your ideas about this are right.  Generally speaking isolate scope is the "right" way to go if you need to have variables accessed and modified within your directive for the reasons you stated.  In some cases no scope for the directive is necessary (simple template directives with or without transclusion for example).

Comment: In additional to your points, one of advantages to use isolate scope is when we try to migrate (a.e. import) directives from one project to another without thinking about dependence.

However, we still can access parent scope using `scope.$parent`

Comment: I've generally seen no good reason not to use isolate scope, given there are various ways to wire up your directives to data in the other scopes, and explicitly defining/restricting input is good for reusability.